# UnixTimeStamp showing 6days ago date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mailer to send on reminder stating the clients last login date. My time is saved in unixtimestamp. So when I fetch from the database and include it in the email then it is giving me 6 days before date. What am I doing wrong here?

Part of the data:

```
$lastlogin = mysql_result($result,$i,"lastlogin");
$newlastlogin = date("d-m-Y", $lastlogin);
```

Email Body:

```
 $msg .= "Your Last Activity: $newlastlogin.<BR>";
```

lastlogin from mysql has date of 27-05-2012

But when the mail goes, then it shows 21-05-2012

By the way, I tried with

```
$newlastlogin = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($lastlogin));
```

Any help and advise would be appreciated

Comment: On my calendar, 27th May is still about 6 days in the future, and 21st May is today.  Did I lose most of a week somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date to a Unix TimeStamp directly from the database using
unix_timestamp(date) on your select statement.

example: (asuming you have a field named last_login on a logins table)

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login) as lastlogin from logins";
```

Details here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp